# asp.net 4.0 project the server tag is not well formed compilation error

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010

I have upgraded projects to .net framework 4.0 (VS 2010) and I am getting lots of "The server tag is not well formed".

for example,
validationgroup="Check has missing closing double quot.
ValidationExpression="[^\"\']*" -- I had to convert that to ValidationExpression="[^& q u o t ; ']*" to make it work.

We have many dozens of web projects and I can go through each of this and correct those things.  This was working fine with VS 2008 (framework 2.0) so I was wondering is there any settings to turn off this kind of validation when compiling the project?

I have tried turning off HTML Validation (Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> HTML -> Unchecked show errors) even though it shows me those error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page parser became stricter in ASP.NET 4.0. You can review details of this and other "breaking changes" that occurred in the newest version on the [ASP.NET 4 Breaking Changes](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes) page.